# Reading permission denied on Ubuntu EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, postgresql, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I am working on executing an a script from my nodejs project that is running on an Ubuntu EC2 instance. I am running into the Error: `error: could not open file "/home/ubuntu/express_bus/database/google_transit/routes.txt" for reading: Permission denied`

This is my second time installing this repo on an instance of this kind, and I didnt run into any sort of permission issues last time so I am very confused.

I looked at the permissions for the file and it appears to me that I do have all the permission I would need to run my `db-load` script. My 'db-create' script is working fine.

Here are my permissions

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-25-137:~/express_bus/database/google_transit$ ls -l
total 98488
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu      276 Nov  5 22:49 agency.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu     7677 Nov  5 22:49 calendar.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu    13648 Nov  5 22:49 calendar_dates.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu      195 Nov  5 22:49 feed_info.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu     3686 Nov  5 22:49 merge_stops.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu     5388 Nov  5 22:49 routes.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 23118892 Nov  5 22:49 shapes.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 73698858 Nov  5 22:49 stop_times.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   409676 Nov  5 22:49 stops.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  3570806 Nov  5 22:49 trips.txt
```

The script is meant to go into main.js and run this,

```
 `import client from './client.js';
    import { copyTxtFiles, insertBusStopRoutesData } from './dataInsertion.js';

    client.connect()
      .then(async () => {
        await copyTxtFiles();
        await insertBusStopRoutesData();
      })
      .finally(async () => {
        await client.end();
        console.log('Database connection closed.');
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(`Error: client.connect chain: ${error}`));

     export default client;`
```

Im really stuck, this all works locally. And i had this repo working on another ubuntu instance before with none of these permission issues.

Happy to provide more of my code if necessary. Thank you

I tried changing the permissions to the routes.txt file and the database folder itself with command, chmod 644 ./database/google_transit/routes.txt.

and

chmod a+r /home/ubuntu/express_bus/database/google_transit/routes.txt

Tried googling and chatGPT but all roads kept pointing me back to changing permissions.

Comment: I think the problem is more likely to be with your filesystem (e.g. is that directory searchable by the running user?) than with the code here, given that you're getting a permission error.

Answer (score 1):

so it turned out to be that the postgres daemon (not sure if im using daemon correctly) was unable to read the files and that was the root of the permission issue.

To fix this I moved the files into the /var directory, changed ownership and granted permission for the postgres user.